# Why in my nuxt-link doesn't reload page with same url?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

If I’m on a page with the URL 'http://localhost:8080/item' and I’m clicking on the same link on this page, then the page does not reload.
I need to make that if I click on the same link, the page will reload.

My link:

```
<nuxt-link :to="/item">
```

Any insight will be welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use key, something like:

```
<router-view :key="$route.params.yourCustomParam"/>
```

Also you can use something like:

```
<router-link :to="{ params: { yourCustomParam: Data.now } }" replace>link</router-link>
```

Remember `to` is passed `router.push()` and it accept an object also. Doing that, it is more declarative and controllable. I'm using this to decide if the page of component should be rerendered since they will based on id params obtained from URL entry, and my child component can still using nesting .

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Perhaps you provide a codesandbox link

Answer (score 1):

I recently tried to solve a similar issue and to overcome this I used `Vuex` with `:key` ([ref](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#key)).

Firstly, in your store you need a `state property` such as:

```
export const state = () => ({
  componentUpdates: {
     item: 0,
     //can add more as needed
  }
})
```

In general, you could use only one property across the app if you prefer it that way. Just remember that later on, the `key` value needs to be unique - that is in the case if you used this property for two or more components within one page, for example. In this case, you could do something like this `:key="$store.getters.getComponentUpdates.item+'uniqueString'"`

---

then a `getter`:

```
export const getters = {
   getComponentUpdates(state) {
      return state.updateComponent;
   }
}
```

finally a `mutatation`:

```
export const mutations = {
  updateComponent(state, payload) {
     return state.componentUpdates[payload.update]++
  }
}
```

Now we can utilise the reactive `:key` wherever needed.
But first in your `nuxt-link` lets add an event to trigger the mutation, note the usage of `@click.native` to trigger the click event:

```
<nuxt-link @click.native="$store.commit('updateComponent', { update: 'item'})" :to="/item">
```

Now in the item page, for example. Let's imagine there is a component that needs to be updated. In this case we would add `:key` to it:

```
<my-item :key="$store.getters.getComponentUpdates.item" />
```

That is it. As you can see this solution utilises the benefits of `nuxt-link` but also allows us to selectively update only parts of our page that need updates (we could update the entire page this way as well if needed).

---

In case if you needed to trigger the logic from `mounted` or initial load in general, then you could use `computed` property and `:key` to your `div` container, right inside the `<template>` of your page.

Add `:key` to the `div`:

```
<template>
  <div :key="$store.getters.getComponentUpdates.item"></div>
</template>
```

Create `computed` property:

```
computed: {
  updateItemPage() {
     //run your initial instructions here as if you were doing it in mounted then return the getter
     this.initialLoadMethod()
     return this.$store.getters.getComponentUpdates.item
  }
}
```

---

The final touch, which is not crucial but can be implemented in order to reset the `state property`:

```
export const mutations = {
  updateComponent(state, payload) {
     return state.componentUpdates[payload.update] >= 10
     ? state.componentUpdates[payload.update] = 0
     : state.componentUpdates[payload.update]++
  }
}
```